# Adding a new factor level to a variable in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have data like this one

```
Id Name Price sales Profit Month Category Mode Supplier
1    A     2     5      8     1        X    K     John
1    A     2     6      9     2        X    K     John
1    A     2     5      8     3        X    K     John
2    B     2     4      6     1        X    L      Sam
2    B     2     3      4     2        X    L      Sam
2    B     2     5      7     3        X    L      Sam
3    C     2     5     11     1        X    M     John
3    C     2     5     11     2        X    L     John
3    C     2     5     11     3        X    K     John
4    D     2     8     10     1        Y    M     John
4    D     2     8     10     2        Y    K     John
4    D     2     5      7     3        Y    K     John
5    E     2     5      9     1        Y    M      Sam
5    E     2     5      9     2        Y    L      Sam
5    E     2     5      9     3        Y    M      Sam
6    F     2     4      7     1        Z    M     Kyle
6    F     2     5      8     2        Z    L     Kyle
6    F     2     5      8     3        Z    M     Kyle
```

with `subset` and `table` I found out which `Category` has how many unique products in which `Mode`.

```
    K L M
  X 2 2 1
  Y 1 1 2
  Z 0 1 1
```

Now I want to add a new entry to `Mode` to this table of `total` so it looks like

```
    K L M Total
  X 2 2 1 5
  Y 1 1 2 4
  Z 0 1 1 2
```

So str(df) will be

```
data.frame':    9 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Category          : Factor w/ 3 levels "X","Y"..: 
 $ Mode:             Factor w/ 3 levels "K","L","M"..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Freq              : int  2,2,1 ...
```

So after I add a new Factor to Mode variable it will become

```
data.frame':    12 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Category          : Factor w/ 3 levels "X","Y"..: 
 $ Mode:             Factor w/ 4 levels "K","L","M", "Total"..: 1 1 11 1 ...
 $ Freq              : int  2,2,1,5 ...
```

So factor level of Mode changed from 3 to 4 and number of observations rised from 9 to 12. 
I can add a new column of total by getting `rowSums` and `cbind` but it won't serve my purpose. I want `Mode` to get a new factor level of `Total` with values from sum of rows.

I hope that I explained it well.

Comment: I started to answer, but then I re-read your question and deleted my answer since I'm confused.  Can you please clarify what " can add a new column of total by getting rowSums and cbind but it won't serve my purpose" means?  `cbind(tab,Total=rowSums(tab))` would seem to be *exactly* what you want ...

Comment: @BenBolker I dont want to add a new column, I want to add a new factor level to Mode variable , Total, which is the sum of all products in a Category.

Comment: I'm still confused.  Can you please edit your question to give us an example of what the output is actually supposed to look like?    Your last code chunk ("so it looks like ...") seems to be *exactly* adding a new column, so I don't understand the difference between that and what you actually want.

Comment: @BenBolker is it clear now?

Comment: not completely, but I've tried again. your new request for the output data frame supposedly has 12 observations.  What would all 12 entries in the "freq" column be ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you want (!) but this might be getting closer???

I think the easiest way to do this is with `plyr`'s `rbind.fill()` function, which will automatically unify factor levels.  You could also do it by hand by converting the factor variable back to a `character` variable before putting the pieces together.

Data:

```
dat2 <- structure(list(Category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("X", 
"Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), Mode = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("K", 
"L", "M"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Category", "Mode"), row.names = c(NA, 
18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Get row totals:

```
tab <- with(dat,addmargins(table(Category,Mode),2))
```

Convert row totals to a data frame:

```
dat3 <- data.frame(Category=rownames(tab),Mode=paste("Total:",tab[,"Sum"]))
```

Concatenate:

```
plyr::rbind.fill(dat2,dat3)
```

Comment: Thank you, after getting the row total with addmargins and converting it into data.frame simply by as.data.frame solved the problem. Using dat3 <- data.frame(Category=rownames(tab),Mode=paste("Total:",tab[,"Sum"])) was showing total as part of variable not the value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another potential way of doing it. I just want to point out that doing it this will will extend the number of rows in the Category and Mode columns, so you'll have to figure out what to do to also extend the other columns in your data frame. Let's first recreate something similar to your Category and Mode columns, then add the 'Total' factor level:

```
> Mode <- factor(sample(c('K', 'L', 'M'), 18, replace=T))    
> Category <- factor(c(rep('X', 9), rep('Y', 6), rep('Z', 3)))
> data.frame(Category=Category, Mode=Mode)
   Category Mode
1         X    M
2         X    K
3         X    K
4         X    M
5         X    K
6         X    K
7         X    K
8         X    M
9         X    L
10        Y    M
11        Y    L
12        Y    M
13        Y    M
14        Y    M
15        Y    M
16        Z    K
17        Z    K
18        Z    L
> table(Category, Mode)
        Mode
Category K L M
       X 5 1 3
       Y 0 1 5
       Z 2 1 0
> Total <- rowSums(table(Category, Mode))
> Category <- factor(c(as.character(Category), rep('X', Total[1]), rep('Y', Total[2]), rep('Z', Total[3])))
> Mode <- factor(c(as.character(Mode), rep('Total', sum(Total))))
> data.frame(Category=Category, Mode=Mode)
   Category  Mode
1         X     M
2         X     K
3         X     K
4         X     M
5         X     K
6         X     K
7         X     K
8         X     M
9         X     L
10        Y     M
11        Y     L
12        Y     M
13        Y     M
14        Y     M
15        Y     M
16        Z     K
17        Z     K
18        Z     L
19        X Total
20        X Total
21        X Total
22        X Total
23        X Total
24        X Total
25        X Total
26        X Total
27        X Total
28        Y Total
29        Y Total
30        Y Total
31        Y Total
32        Y Total
33        Y Total
34        Z Total
35        Z Total
36        Z Total
> table(Category, Mode)
        Mode
Category K L M Total
       X 5 1 3     9
       Y 0 1 5     6
       Z 2 1 0     3
```